# How do I set default settings for all program listings in a Lyx document?

Tags: lyx

I know that I can change the language, placement, and highlighting details of a listing in `Settings`. How do I set the default settings for all listings?

Answer (score 3):

Found it: `Document` > `Document Settings` > `Listings`.